# get substring after delimiter

Tags: php, string

I have this string "9|Engineering" and I need to get this part "Engineering" from it, I'm trying to use this piece of code:

```
substr($program,0,strrpos($program,'|',2))
```

but I'm getting nothing, can you please help?

Comment: might want to consider explode v. substr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use `str_replace()`

```
$str = "9|Engineering";
echo str_replace('9|', '', $str); //Engineering
```

or

```
$str = "9|Engineering";
echo substr($str,2); //Engineering
```

or use `explode()`

```
$str = "9|Engineering";
$re = explode('|', $str); 
echo $re[1];//Engineering
```

Comment: I want it to be general thing, not just for this string. So I might have bigger number that 9 I mean two digits number !

Answer (score 0):

This would be one way to do it.

```
substr($program, strrpos($program,'|') + 1);
```

I would also read up on regex. It is a much better (but harder) way to extract stuff from strings.

Answer (score 0):

Better than explode:

```php
$str = "WhateverHere9|Engineering";
echo substr(strstr($str, '|'), 1);
```

Dependings on if you want the string after the first or last "|".

- For the first occurence, use strstr()
- For the last occurence, use strrchr()